# How to get value out of anonymous function in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to learn scala and understand difference between functions and methods.

Here is very simple code I  wrote -

```
 scala> class C ( acc:Int) {
       |  val minc = ( acc + 1 )
       |  val func = { () => acc += 3 }
       | }

  scala> val c1 = new C(3)
         c1: C = C@55e610e3

  scala> c1.minc
         res2: Int = 4

  scala> c1.func
         res3: () => Int = <function0>
```

I understand that result of calling function func on instantiated object c1 is stored as another expression res3.

However I want to get value out of of anonymous function () = acc +3 that is inside class C.

If I try to pass argument to res3 expression scala throws an error

```
  scala> res3(4)
   <console>:11: error: too many arguments for method apply: ()Int in trait    Function0
   res3(4)
        ^
```

How to get value out of it ?

PS -  I have just started with scala and don't know if this is at all possible or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your definition of `func`:

```
val func = { () => acc += 3 }
```

Let's take a look in the REPL at what is the type of `func`.

```
scala> val c1 = new C(3)
val c1 = new C(3)
c1: C = C@58db88e9

scala> c1.func
c1.func
res29: () => Unit = <function0>
```

In plain English, this means "func refers to a function that accepts no arguments and doesn't return a value."  `Unit` means the method doesn't return anything.  If you're coming from Java, then it's analogous to `void` as the return type.  `function0` means it accepts 0 arguments.

Next, let's take a look at the failing call in your example.

```
scala> c1.func(4)
c1.func(4)
<console>:10: error: too many arguments for method apply: ()Unit in trait Function0
              c1.func(4)
                     ^
```

Now that we know the method signature of `func`, this error message should make more sense.  We know that `func` refers to a function that accepts no arguments, yet in this call, you have attempted to call it with a single integer argument.  Since the method call has too many arguments, Scala correctly reports this as an error.

I am not entirely sure what you were trying to do by passing `4` as an argument.  My best guess is that you are trying to apply the function to calculate its result by adding `3` to `acc` and then returning it to the caller.  If I'm right, then we can redefine `C` as this:

```
class C(var acc:Int) {
  val minc = ( acc + 1 )
  val func = () => {
    acc += 3
    acc
}

scala> val c1 = new C(3)
val c1 = new C(3)
c1: C = C@58db88e9

scala> c1.func()
c1.func()
res44: Int = 6
```

When we call `c1.func()`, no arguments are passed, so it correctly matches the defined method signature.

Another possibility is that you were trying to parameterize the increment amount and pass `4` to it in the call.  If so, then you can do this:

```
class C(var acc:Int) {
  val minc = ( acc + 1 )
  val func = (delta: Int) => {
    acc += delta
    acc
  }
}

scala> c1.func(4)
c1.func(4)
res45: Int = 7
```

In this case, we have declared that the anonymous function accepts 1 argument of type `Int`, so when we pass `4` in the method call, it correctly matches the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You're not declaring an anonymous function in the way you think. This line:

```
val func = { () => acc += 3 }
```

That actually declares **2** anonymous functions. The brackets are the first anonymous function (that takes no arguments), and the `() => acc += 3` is the second function. Scala allows you to declare a 0-arity anonymous function by just using brackets. If you drop those, you'll have what you want:

```
val func = () => acc += 3
```

As a bit of a side note, you can see this in the type signature. Your current signature for `func` is:

```
() => Int = <function0>
```

That's a function that takes 0 arguments and returns an integer. That's not what you want. When you change it to what I gave you, you'll get this:

```
Int => Int = <function1>
```

Now `func` takes a single argument, and Integer, and returns another Integer, which is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !  However, I am still seeing error when I try to get value out of function.

class c ( acc:Int) {
         val minc = ( acc + 1 )
         val func =  () =>  acc + 3 
        }

val  c1 = new C(5)
c1.minc  print 6

but,  c1.func prints res23: () => Int = <function0>

I am expecting output 8  out of this object.  Is there any other method I should be using to get value from func  ?